# Does Roslyn enable or potentially enable multiple langugage projects?

Tags: roslyn

The current .Net compilers are entirely separate.  Roslyn is supposed to combine them into a single compiler.  Does anyone know if this would introduce the ability to have multiple languages in a single project?  Or even possibly in a single file/class?

The best you can do at the moment, is to have multiple projects in a solution, but I'd really like to see multiple languages in a single project, and I'm hoping that Roslyn might eventually lead to that.

Comment: To whoever made the close vote: I don't think this is opinion based.  The answer could be yes, or it could be no with reference to technical details in Roslyn that makes it difficult or impossible to add. Either way, I don't see this question as asking for an option.  I'm not asking if Microsoft is likely to add the ability, but whether the tool (which is open source) does. If I was to take a class on compiler writing and/or study the source long enough, I think I could answer this question without it being an opinion -- hopefully someone that has done one or the other (or both) can do so now.

Comment: Your question may not be opinion-based but the title is, which is probably the reason for the close vote. You should consider editing it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is no. We considered that possible requirement when we started the Roslyn project and decided that it is out of scope. The Roslyn C# and VB compilers share much code, but they are separate compilers. The symbol table models are separate. For a symbol representing a class in C#, symbol.Members("x") returns all members named lower-case x. The same method in the VB symbol-table model returns all members named lower-case x AND all members named upper-case x.

We could have designed the "Members" method to take an additional parameter that says whether or not the lookup should be case-dependent or case-independent, but we didn't do that. The C# symbol table has internal data required by the C# compiler, and the VB symbol table has internal data required by the VB compiler, and they are implemented separately.